# Control style of plain text in CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got an HTML page that contains some plain text (...)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hi there!
  </body>
</html>
```

(...) and the CSS file associated with it:

```
body {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
}
```

The problem is, the plain text's font will still be the default one, not Segoe UI. What can I do? I know that I can fit the text between two `<p></p>` tags and add a special style for it but I don't want that.

Some advice? Thanks.

Comment: Works for me as is.

Comment: make sure you link you're css file correctly.

Comment: Check your css file name correct or not.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jeYaMM check this link you're code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your `font-family` declaration should be enclosed in double quotes (`"`) when referencing a font with whitespace in the name:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  Hi there!
</body>

</html>
```

From MDN docs:

> Font family names containing whitespace should be quoted.

<sup>[Mozilla Developer Network - `font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family)</sup>

Comment: It should be, but that only makes a difference if the font name is preceeded or followed by whitespace or has multiple sequential whitespace.

Comment: @Quentin correct - I've added a bit of clarification on that point.

Comment: Oh my God, thank you so much! This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Font families that are not default, should always be enclosed by quotes.

So: `font-family: "Segoe UI";` should do the trick.

If that doesnt work, check if you are actually including the font in your CSS

Comment: "Font families that are not default, should always be enclosed by quotes." — Not true. Only font names with multiple whitespace or which have whitespace before the first character or after the last one need quoting.

Comment: [MDN paints a different picture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) - you'll notice that they've referenced `Georgia` as an unencapsulated string in their first example.